# DRF: how to mix model fields directly inside a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have

```
class Model1(models.Model)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I want to create a serializer using these fields.

This has nothing to do with the models or the POST transaction. Just i want to use the definition of the models

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ['first_name']
        model = Model2
        fields = ['location']
```

So that i dont have to define them again.

Comment: is there any relation between model1 and model2?

Comment: No relation between them

Comment: then how do you connect the location data to the users?

Comment: Rather than mixing the models in a serializer, can you just describe what you want to achieve by doing that? I'm sure there's a better way to achieve what you want, but you're limiting yourself. A simple expected output using this models would makes it easy to understand for everyone.